# Endless Rotating DIV but with Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm facing a problem, I have a div with an absolute position, and I'm trying to rotate it 360 degrees with an endless looping. But if I use the transform: translate (-50%,-50%) to fully center this div, it won't work properly.

HTML

```
<div class="randomName"></div>
```

CSS

```
.randomName {
background-color: orange;
width: 1500px;
height: 1500px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
-o-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbita {
0%  {transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}  
}
```

Not sure why is not working. Can someone guide me? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the animation you are **overriding** the initial transform property by  specifying a new one. Instead you need to append rotation to translate in order to keep both of them working:

```css
.randomName {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbita {
  0% {
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="randomName"></div>
```

Another solution is to center your element using another way and keep the animation as it is.

*Here is an example using flex to center the element:*

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.randomName {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: orbita 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbita {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="randomName"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @Temani Afif I've learned a lot with you tonight:D!! so great!!

Comment: One quick question @Temani Afif Now that's corrected, why If I increase the size of the Div to 4000px height and 4000px width, while rotating there's a point that the squared shape of the div reduces drastically while rotating to look more like a rectangle? (so you can see the background by mistake while rotating instead of covering it entire). My idea is to have a background color for the body, and this div will be a stars png image rotating slowly simulating space, but the div of the stars image (the one we have been working to fully center) reduces size while rotating?

Comment: @Eugenio so i assume you have a big screen ? as for may case if i put 1500px i can't see the body background ... First i suggest to add `overflow:hidden` to body to avoid some bad effect, then instead of px you can use vh/vw unit so you can make size of square relative the viewport( try for example 400vh (height) and 400vw (width))

Comment: is really strange, I don't understand what's going on. Already have the body with an overflow:hidden; Also, rounded the div with border-radius: 50%; just to check if the distortion was really happening. and found that yes, if you increase the size of the div to 2x the size of screen with 200vw and 200vh it keeps distorting the element, you can see borders around it from the background. Let me show you, I'll prepare a JsFiddle:)

Comment: but if you increase the size of the div to be larger than the screen. let's say 5000px X 5000px even with that it keeps showing body background color on corners while rotating like here https://jsfiddle.net/70Loxsvo/1/ @Temani Afif

Comment: @Eugenio since your element is not more absolute position and we use flex you have this behavior ... in my example i used small element which is fine, but since you need your element to bigger than the screen, so it's better to use the first method

Comment: ohh excellent pal you're right!!! now it works properly:D thanks a lot! @Temani Afif